# Не понимаю как передаются байты с консоли в программу

Tags: java, standards

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, если я буду нажимать следующие клавиши по очереди: {`a`,`enter`,`b`,`enter`,`q`, `enter`}, то я увижу ужасно странный вывод, который отделяет предыдущий ввод от нынешнего ~пятью сносами строки?

Код:

```
BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char c;
do {
    c = (char)in.read();
    System.out.println(c);
} while (c!='q');
```

Ожидание:

```
a
a
b
b
q
```

Реальность:

```
a
a




b
b




q
q
```

Даже если думать, что при нажатии на `enter` отправляется ещё и непосредственно `\n` в поток, то вывод должен быть такой после первой введённой буквы:

```
a
a


b...
```

Т.е. от куда ещё выводится один снос строки?...

---

Смешно ещё, что такой код будет давать ожидаемый результат:

```
BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
do {
    s = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
} while (!s.equals("q"));
```

Comment: замените `System.out.println(c)` на `System.out.println((int)c)`

Comment: уже делал, и не могу понять этих трёх чисел: код символа, 13, 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С Вашего первого примера у меня выводит, если "слушать" коды то:

```
a (сам ввод в консоль)
97 (код буквы в ASCII)
10 (LF, код переноса строки) // далее ниже следующие символы
b
98
10
q
113
```

Предполагаю, что т.к `char` это один символ, то и перенос строки `\n` (исходит, вероятно, от **Enter**) выводится при печати как отдельный символ. Если использовать метод без переноса строки, а именно System.out.**print()**, то:

```
a
a
b
b
q
q
```

Если в кодах:

```
a
9710b
9810q
113
```

Comment: мой вывод: a
97
13
10

Comment: b 98 13 10, q 113 13 10

Comment: 13 это символ переноса каретки, возможно, особенности среды

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но у меня и с консоли, и с eclips'а -- отовсюду валят снос и перенос каретки. Я не понимаю от куда это. Какой-то дикий психоз, когда не может в трёх соснах разобраться

Comment: Да, среда быть может добавляет это, но консоль?....

Comment: Я тесты проводил в NetBeans

Comment: @Direct, в консоли символ каретки есть.